# JCEF (Java Chromium Embedded Framework) Browser does not load content; only blank screen on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, chromium-embedded

I have been trying to get the Java version of Chromium Embedded Framework (JCEF) to work on Eclipse for some time. I am able to verify that the library files are working correctly, since if I run the included sample class files on the VM, the program runs and some webpage is displayed. However, if I run the program from Eclipse, the program will always display a blank window. I am able to verify that the library binary `jcef_helper.exe` is successfully run, but not matter how I link the .jar files and other library files, the webpage will not generate and there will always be a blank screen. I cannot pinpoint the issue here. I tried specifying path, adding the JCEF library path of my OS environment variables PATH field to no avail. I have followed the documentation, even sample files behave the same way when I have anything to do with compilation/ run. One note of interest, my Eclipse console will display this during run:

```
initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
```

Perhaps there is a thread issue?

Code in question:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import org.cef.CefApp;
import org.cef.CefApp.CefAppState;
import org.cef.CefClient;
import org.cef.CefSettings;
import org.cef.browser.CefBrowser;
import org.cef.handler.CefAppHandlerAdapter;

public class WebV
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Dimension dispDimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int width = (int)Math.round(dispDimension.getWidth() / 2);
        int height = (int)Math.round(dispDimension.getHeight() / 2);

        CefApp.addAppHandler(new CefAppHandlerAdapter(null)
        {
            @Override
            public void stateHasChanged(CefAppState state)
            {
                if(state == CefAppState.TERMINATED)
                {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = false;
        CefApp cefApp = CefApp.getInstance(settings);
        CefClient client = cefApp.createClient();
        CefBrowser browser = client.createBrowser("http://www.google.com", false, false);
        Component browserComponent = browser.getUIComponent();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("WebV");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.add(browserComponent);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Tested with both **Java 17** and **Java 8**.
Run on Eclipse, with VM args:

```
-Djava.library.path=./bin/lib/win64
```

Any inupt would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: The JCEF support forum at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=17 would be where I'd ask questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was kindly provided by 'Yanovsky' at the JCEF forums.
The simple example provided by the JCEF package is incomplete.
We need to add a `CefMessageRouter` instance to our browser client. This is demonstrated in the detailed examples, but not the simple one. This code should be added *before* we create our `CefBrowser` instance and *after* we have created a `CefClient` object:

```
CefMessageRouter msgRouter = CefMessageRouter.create();
msgRouter.addHandler(new MessageRouterHandler(), true);
msgRouter.addHandler(new MessageRouterHandlerEx(client), false);
client.addMessageRouter(msgRouter);
```

For reference, this is my post in the JCEF forum:
https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=18834&sid=45381db639d1621f2f8b38b4d8848800

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and pasted your code in eclipse and added the jars and ran the code and voila, google.com opened without any issues.

I didnt have to add any more new lines as suggested by mindoverflow.

The webpage was visible in the window after a few secs and not immediately.
[Here's what popped up after running the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HQiJ.png)
[image]

And in the eclipse console, I see this

> initialize on Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] with library path C:\path\to\dlls

Comment: Perhaps they have addressed the issue. However, this bug was indeed confirmed by a moderator of JCEF. Are you perhaps runing some other OS? This is an issue mainly with Windows.